# "document security not valid" when attempting to open an online document

Tags: security, sharepoint-2013

This message comes up seemingly randomly and infrequently when clicking a link that opens a document on a different server. Searching for results brings up the 2 inquiries that I've made on it. Any ideas on what may be causing this?

We are running SharePoint 2013 on prem where the link is clicked and the endpoint for that URL is on a website that is also part of our domain. The user is authenticated and authorized in both locations.

Comment: Check the security credentials for the document via another channel. You may (only *may*) have a Man In The Middle .